# Unity - Make player point toward mouse

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input, keyboard, top-down

Im making a top-down shooter, where the player moves up, down, left, and right with WASD and constantly points toward the mouse. I want the movement to be irrelevant to the direction the player is pointing, but right now thats not the case.

Here is my code:

```
void Update() 
{
  float igarH = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
  float igarV = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
  if (igarH > 0.5f || igarH < -0.5f) 
  {
    transform.Translate(new Vector3(igarH * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0f, 0f));
  }
  if (igarV > 0.5f || igarV < -0.5f)
  {
    transform.Translate(new Vector3(0f, igarV * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0f));
  }

  // Point toward mouse
  Vector2 direction = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - transform.position;
  float angle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.y, direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
  Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);
  transform.rotation = rotation;
}
```

Sorry about the bad indentation, its kind of hard to figure out how the site wants me to do the markup, and I'm new to this site.

Why is the player moving differently based on where my mouse is? I want movement to be the same no matter what.

Please keep all answers related to Unity2D and not 3D, please.

Comment: _I want movement to be the same no matter what._ Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: Well, I want W to make him move straight up. Right now it kinda moves *toward* the mouse instead.

Comment: Have you tried just removig the code below `// Point toward mouse`?

Comment: Also, there is no such a thing as _Unity2D_. Unity3D is the name of the framework, no matter if you are restricting your objects to 2D.

Comment: If I removed that code, it wouldnt point toward the mouse at all. I want the player to always point toward the mouse, while also moving in the directions of arrow keys/wasd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Transform.Translate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html) has an optional parameter `relativeTo`, in that you choose if you want the object to move relative to its own corrdinate system or the world coordinate system.

Just change your calls to:

```
if (igarH > 0.5f || igarH < -0.5f) {
  transform.Translate(new Vector3(igarH * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0f, 0f), Space.World);
}
if (igarV > 0.5f || igarV < -0.5f) {
  transform.Translate(new Vector3(0f, igarV * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0f), Space.World);
}
```